# Jsoup whitelist sanitizer for data-* attributes

Tags: html, json, jsoup, whitelist

Utilizing the jsoup whitelist sanitizer to clean html prior to being serialized (json) and ajaxed.

How  to allow for all data-* attributes in html without having to explicitly add each instance to the whitelist?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and created an [issue](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/499) on JSoup's GitHub project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in function for that. What you could do though is, take your html string, search for every data attribute (a regex would be a good idea) and add them in a loop explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this option did not exist 10 years ago. This is how I solved this problem:

```java
Safelist safelist = new Safelist() {
    public boolean isSafeAttribute(String tagName, Element el, Attribute attr) {
        if (attr.getKey().startsWith("data-")) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.isSafeAttribute(tagName, el, attr);
    }
};
safelist.addTags(...);
String html = "...";
html = Jsoup.clean(html, safelist);
```